# Geometrical interpretation of a function of two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$, $B$ be real $n \times n$ matrices and $v$ a column vector of length $n$. The expression $$\dfrac{v^T A^T B v}{v^T A^T A v}$$ appears to measure some kind of "closeness" between $A$ and $B$, since when $A = B$ the expression equals one. Is there a geometrical interpretation of the quantity this expression is measuring?

Context: The expression arises when projecting $B v$ onto the subspace spanned by $A v$.

Comment: Where did you come upon this expression? What is the context?

Comment: You are basically looking at the ratio of two quadratic forms.

Comment: @Christoph I have added context to the question.

Comment: The expression is a generalized Rayleigh quotient.

Comment: @greg I notice that, though $A^T A$ in the denominator is of course symmetric, $A^T B$ in the numerator is in general not symmetric. Since the whole expression must evaluate to a real number, can upper and lower bounds for this number be obtained by solving the generalized eigenvalue problem?

Comment: Solve the generalized EV problem, and select the _real_ eigenvalues to obtain $\{\lambda_{min},\lambda_{max}\}.\;$ **NB**: There might not be any real EVs.